# Запятая перед «как»

Tags: пунктуация

"Символизирует рукопожатие, как первый шаг на пути к доверию". Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не нужна, союз "как" имеет значение "в качестве".

***Символизирует рукопожатие как первый шаг на пути к доверию.***

Ср.: ***Символизирует рукопожатие в качестве первого шага на пути к доверию.***

Answer (score 0):

"Символизирует рукопожатие, как первый шаг на пути к доверию". Нужна ли запятая перед "как" в этом предложении? Для полноты картины хотелось бы узнать, ЧТО символизирует рукопожатие. Я тоже думаю, что запятая перед КАК не нужна, потому что рукопожатие не сравнивается с первым шагом, а является им (первым шагом). Следовательно, запятую ставить не надо.